# Compile time check constructors with same signature

Tags: c++, constructor, compile-time

Is it possible to check, at compile time, if two constructors belonging to two different classes have the same signature?
And if it is possible, how to implement it?

Example:

```
struct A
{
    A(int){}
};

struct B
{
    B(int){}
};

int main()
{
    static_assert(std::same_signature< A::A , B::B >::value, "A and B must have the same constructor parameters");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide some sample code. How would you use such a trait?

Comment: Trying something with [`decltype`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) together with [the type support functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types) might work.

Comment: How do you want to handle default arguments?

Comment: @TartanLlama question edited with example code

Comment: @JoachimPileborg could you be more precise or provide a code solution? What you said sounds right to me but it seems I'm not skilled enough to implement a working version myself...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath It is ok a basic implementation which can't handle default arguments. Maybe next question will be about that.

Comment: You can't ever get that usage syntax (nor adding `&`) because **constructors do not have names** (First sentence of 12.1).  Everywhere it appears that you name a constructor in C++, it's actually a special construct of the grammar.  There is no such construct for creating a pointer or reference to member function from a constructor.

Comment: Now, that doesn't immediately rule out the syntax `same_constructor_signatures< A, B >::value` ... but inspection of signatures is quite hard when all you have is SFINAE, no pointer-to-member-function, no type inference or template deduction.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to check, at compile time, if two constructors belonging to two different classes have the same signature?

Not exactly what you want, but you can check if `class A` and `class B` can
be constructed from the same types using such construction `CheckConstructable<A, B, types...>::value`, c++11:

```
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

struct A { A(int){} };

struct B { B(int){} B(std::string) {} };

struct C { C(std::string) {} };

template<class A, class B, typename... Types>
struct CheckConstructable;

template<class A, class B>
struct CheckConstructable<A, B> {
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};

template<class A, class B, typename T1, typename... Types>
struct CheckConstructable<A, B, T1, Types...> {
    static constexpr bool cur_type_ok = std::is_constructible<A, T1>::value && std::is_constructible<B, T1>::value;
    static constexpr bool value = cur_type_ok || CheckConstructable<A, B, Types...>::value;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Have the same: " << (CheckConstructable<A, B, int, std::string>::value ? "yes" : "no") << "\n";
    std::cout << "Have the same: " << (CheckConstructable<A, B, std::string>::value ? "yes" : "no") << "\n";
    std::cout << "Have the same: " << (CheckConstructable<A, C, std::string>::value ? "yes" : "no") << "\n";
    std::cout << "Have the same: " << (CheckConstructable<B, C, std::string, int>::value ? "yes" : "no") << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Great code, this can partially solve the problem, if I just could extract the parameters in some variadic way like 'Args...' or similar